# Moment.js subtract function not working with custom date

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, datepicker, react-datepicker

I want to subtract 30 days from a moment date.

However, **this is not working when I use the subtract function**.

```
moment('19-Aug-2021').subtract(30, 'days')

const latestDate = moment('19-Aug-2021')
latestDate.subtract(30, 'days')
```

both the above print out '19-Aug-2021'.

However, **the below works all fine.**

```
moment().subtract(30, 'days')
```

Why is this happening and what is the correct way to get subtract to work with a date of my choice ?

Comment: That's because you're using a non supported format, like the warning from `moment` says: "Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions.". You should try using a different date format, for example: `moment('2021-08-19T00:00:00Z').subtract(30, 'days')`

Answer (score 0):

***Found the answer from a friend.***

I was trying to do

```
a = moment(b).subtract(30, 'days')
```

What the above does is it changes the value of b to b - 30 days. And makes a = b.

So the correct way to do this would be

```
a = moment(b)
a = moment(a).subtract(30,'days')
```